# Handling GotFocus when using BringIntoView in WPF

Tags: wpf, focus

I am scrolling to different items in a control, and using .BringIntoView(Rect) rather than .Focus(), so I can buffer the size around the control, so when I focus on something, its not just at the very top or bottom of the main control.

When calling Focus, one can catch GotFocus() to then fire an event when the control has received focus. But this does not fire when using BringIntoView().

I would like to know when a control received focus so I can highlight it to the user so they know where their content went. Is there any way to when control.BringIntoView has completed so I can then do something to notify the user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because BringIntoView does not activate focus on the control.

Simply call the Focus method on your control reference as well as calling BringIntoView.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Can one call focus on it before bringintoview? Because if I call focus afterwards, it defeats the purpose of doing BringIntoView separately.

Answer (score 0):

Create your custom event and raises that event when you call BringIntoView.